# How to apply rand() or some other built-in function on an array that contains all string elements in order to randomly select a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, random, compiler-warnings

I've a following array :

```
$family = array("Amit", "Suresh", "Vinit", "Somesh", "Sagar", "Shriram");
```

Now I want to randomly select a name from the above array.

How should I do this?

I know about rand() function. Even I tried `rand($family);` but it gave me Warning as below :

**Warning: rand() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/project/index.php on line 7**

It's asking for second argument.

So please someone help me in selecting a string randomly from an array that contains all string elements.

Thanks.

Comment: All of the answers below will work, array_rand is a built in function.  However, from my experience, if you want a more statistically accurate result, you'll need to use mt_rand() over rand().

Comment: @Devon:Thanks for the information you provided but it would be great if you could demonstrate the idea with the help of some useful example and post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Take the rand() examples below and replace rand() with mt_rand().  Test it and you'll see what I mean about statistically accurate.  rand() tends to favor certain numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the docs first, there is exact function you are looking for in example

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

```
<?php
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Array_rand() seems a good option, but as it's based on the biased libc based rand() function, it's not that as a good array random picker. Check the comments in the docs that you've pointed out. Use my_rand(), or random_int() of you have php 7. Check my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$num = rand(0, count($family)-1);
$family[$num]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Count the elements    
$count = count($family);
// decrement the count by 1
$count--;
// echo a random item from the array
echo $family[rand(0, $count)];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `rand()` function takes either zero or two arguments. With zero arguments it will produce a pseudo random integer between 0 and `getrandmax()`. Otherwise it expects two integer arguments `min` and `max` and will produce a pseudo random integer between `min` and `max` inclusive.

As @Yurich pointed out this is what you probably want.

```
$num = rand(0, count($family-1));
$family[$num]
```

Explanation: `rand(0, count($family-1))` will produce a random integer between 0 and the number of elements in your array minus one. This number will be stored in `$num`, which is used afterwards to access the array at a "random" index.

Answer (score 1):

rand() is not a good option, and for PHP 7 there is a better option. See below:

```
$family = array("Amit", "Suresh", "Vinit", "Somesh", "Sagar", "Shriram");

if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION,'7.0.0', '<') ) {
    // for PHP < 7
    $rand_name = $family[mt_rand(0, count($family) - 1)];
} else {
    // for PHP >= 7
    $rand_name = $family[random_int(0, count($family) - 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = rand(0, count($family)-1);
$family[$num]
```